# django no encripta las contraseñas importadas desde un excel

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, djangorestframework, python-import

estoy usando django-import-export para poder importar usuarios desde el admin, y mi finalidad es usar el dni como usuario y contraseña, hasta ahi todo ok. pero cuando intento iniciar session con uno de los usuarios importados django no reconoce mi contraseña, entre al admin y muestra un mensaje diciendo que
Formato de clave incorrecto o algoritmo de hash desconocido. cuando tengo entendido que django se encarga de encriptar mediasnte hash las contraseñas. intente ingresar usuarios desde consola con el mismo formato y desde ahi no tengo error pero mi finalidad es importarlos ya que son miles.

este es mi model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,BaseUserManager

class User(AbstractUser):
    dni = models.CharField('DNI/ PTP/ Cedula',null=True,max_length=10)
    username = models.CharField('Usuario', max_length=150,primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.username)
```

mi admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from import_export import resources,fields,widgets
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from .models import *
from import_export.fields import Field
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget,ManyToManyWidget 

class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('last_name', 'first_name','dni','username','password')
        export_order = ('last_name', 'first_name','dni','username','password')
        exclude = ('id', )
        import_id_fields = ['username'] # import busca un id por default especificar que campo utilizare como id si cambio el pk

   
        
class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, BaseUserAdmin):
    list_display = ('username','dni')
    search_fields = ['username','dni']
    resource_class = UserResource 


#Registrar  Usuarios en el panel administrativo

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Ten presente que a nadie se le ocurre guardar contraseñas "planas" de modo que lo que **importas son contraseñas encriptadas**. Si luego tratas de registrarlos usando los métodos normales **es posible** que ellos apliquen **nuevamente hash** al guardar. Te sugeriría usar un mecanismo de guardado propio que te asegure que guardas tal cual leíste al registrar la info importada. **Antes de intentar otras soluciones verifica que guardaste tal como leíste**.

Comment: se que guardar contraseñas planas es malo por eso intento aplicar hash antes de que se realice la importacion, intente con before_import_row y aun no se aplica el hash

Comment: El tema es que las que lees a importar **no son planas** ya están hasheadas, de modo que aplicas doble hash y haces imposible validar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha pasado tiempo desde que hice esta pregunta y ya me habia resignado pero aqui la solucion que encontre. hacer una hash a la columna password antes de importarlo.

```
"from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from import_export import resources,fields,widgets
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):

def before_import_row(self,row, **kwargs):
       password = row['password']
       row['password'] = make_password(password)
       

class Meta: 
   model = User

   exclude = ('id', )
   import_id_fields = ['username'] 

class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, BaseUserAdmin):
list_display = ('username','dni')
search_fields = ['username','dni']
resource_class = UserResource 


#Registrar  Usuarios en el panel administrativo

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)"
```